# Would him or his go for this sentence?

Tags: grammaticality, personal-pronouns

I came across the following sentence in a workbook:

> **There was a possibility of ... (he) going to England.**

The book says the answer is *his*, not *him*.

Would **him** be grammatically incorrect? If so, why?

Comment: And, to answer your question anyway, *him* should be correct there, especially in informal style as there's an observed tendency of *regularizing the clausal construction*. Namely, *The Cambridge Grammar of the English Language* by Huddleston and Pullum (2002) analyzes both *him going to England* and *his going to England* as gerund-participial constructions (non-finite clauses) (in this case functioning as complements to the preposition *of*) where both *him* and *his* (noun phrases) function as (optional) subjects.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Prescriptive grammars long taught that **his** was correct there and **him** was incorrect, the goal being to educate the **him** (dative) + participle construction out of existence.

Kids would go to school saying **a chance of him going to London** and graduate, knuckles bloody, saying **a chance of his going to London**.